# How to download image to gallery in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, file-upload, flutter-layout

I am working with school management application, here I need to send the image and video to the app and allow user to download the image and video to their phone Gallery. I am stuck with this!
Please do help me.. Thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the function that might help

```
saveImage(String url) async {
    
    var response = await Dio()
        .get(url, options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
        Uint8List.fromList(response.data),
        quality: 100,
        name: "${widget.id}");
  }
```

in order to use this function you have to install two packages(And them in your pubspec.ymal file) :

```
dio: ^3.0.10
image_gallery_saver: '^1.5.0'
```

Comment: Thank you. but can this work when the image is arriving through API?

Comment: Well if you are use using firebase yes. Else it may or may not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ElevatedButton(
              onPressed:()async{
                try{
                  // Get the ByteData for the asset image
                  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('backgrounds/$nameOfImage.jpg');
                  List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

                  // Get the external storage directory
                  Directory? externalStorageDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

                  // Create a File object with the appropriate path
                  File file = File(path.join(externalStorageDirectory!.path, '$nameOfImage.jpg'));

                  // Write the image bytes to the file
                  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

                  // Save the image to the gallery
                  await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(file.path, isReturnPathOfIOS: true);

                  // Show a dialog indicating success
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text('Image saved to gallery successfully'),
                    ),
                  );
                }catch (e) {
                      print('Error: $e');
                      // Handle the error (show a snackbar, display an error message, etc.)
                            }
                          },
              child: Text('Download')),
```

Comment: also add permission to read and write in manifest ,and add path_provide package , path.dart ,dart:core and dart:io

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Hi @Nega , It will save in downloads folder ryt ?

Comment: @Anand hi , no It will save on Gallary

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).