# Create an image, some text and how to save it with flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

My project will have images and text in a stack widget, a "download" button on the outside. How can I download it as a photo when I press the download button?

The structure example;
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful brother and I wonder you could have seen it already but take a look.

> [How to download image to gallery in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502183/how-to-download-image-to-gallery-in-flutter)

```
saveImage(String url) async {

var response = await Dio()
    .get(url, options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
    Uint8List.fromList(response.data),
    quality: 100,
    name: "${widget.id}");
}
```

Install the following packages:

```
dio: ^3.0.10
image_gallery_saver: '^1.5.0'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How do i get the filePath in string variable?

Comment: Often the URL is considered the file path.  Sorry, I don't know what you mean by 'getting the filePath.

Answer (score 1):

use the

> **flutter_downloader package.**

This is the flutter community official's Plugin

Comment: Can you give a basic example that how can i do?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `onPressed` function to your button widget. Point towards the image you want to download.

```
onPressed: () {
    // do something 
}
```

Comment: I know. But how i convert widget to image and download in onpressed method?

Comment: I think you need to understand  the difference between a widget and an image first. You cannot download a widget, just like an image isn’t the widget. You create a widget which may render an image. Have you any code you can show?